# beforeunload function just working on reload and not when i navigate to another Reactjs page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a component in reactjs where i have a form to add a new product. I wish i could show an alert everytime the user have a filled field and try to navigate to another page (i have a side and a navbar, so there are a lot of options of navigation in my screen). I tryed to use a window.beforeunload that i saw here in stackoverflow, but it didn't work when he navigate to another page, only when he refresh the page. It should also do that (show when refresh) but I need to warn him when he leave and just leave if he click in 'ok'. How can i do that?

```
function ProIncluir(){
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    console.log('unload');
    return "Leaving this page will reset the wizard";
};
```

return (

```
  <div className="sidebar-content fixed-top">
    <SidebarPrincipal/>
    <div id="espaco-padrao">
      <Navbar/>
        <div className="row scrollable-content">
            <GrupoModal 
                isOpen={isGrupoModalOpen}
                onRequestClose={fechaGrupoModal}
                dadosGrupos={dadosGrupos}
                adicionarNovoGrupo={adicionarNovoGrupo} 
            />
            {/* {ReactRouterPrompt} */}
           

            <div className="d-flex" id="titulo-pagina"> 
                <span> <Link to={linkVoltar} className="link-voltar-titulo" >Produtos</Link> {caminho} Incluir  </span>                    
            </div>
            <div onClick={avancar} className="link-avancar-pro-incluir">
                <div className="next-page-produto-incluir">
                    <i className="fa fa-solid fa-xs fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="conteudo-padrao" className="card-body">
                <div id="inside-conteudo-padrao">
                    <form className="mb-4">
                        <div className='row justify-content-center text-center mb-5'>
                            <div className="progressbar col-9 ">
                                <div>
                                    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
                                    <ul id="progress-num">
                                        <li className="step active">1<br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small">Principal</small></li>
                                        <li className="step">2<br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small-lg">Características</small></li>
                                        <li className="step">3<br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small">Impostos</small><br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small">Estaduais</small></li>
                                        <li className="step">4<br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small">Impostos</small><br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small">Federais</small></li>
                                        <li className="step">5<br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small-sm">Balança</small></li>
                                        <li className="step">6<br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small-lg">Composição</small></li>
                                        <li className="step">7<br/><small id="pro-incluir-li-small-sm">Grade</small></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="first-row-inclusao"></div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-1 mt-3 mb-2'>
                                <div className='form-check' id="ativo-pro-incluir">
                                    <input onChange={(e) => setPro_ativo(e.target.checked)} defaultChecked={pro_ativo} id="pro-incluir-input" className='form-check-input' type="checkbox"/>
                                    <label className='form-check-label' htmlFor="defaultcheck1">Ativo</label>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className='col-lg-3'>
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Grupo<i className="fa-solid fa-asterisk fa-2xs" style={{color: "#e41607"}} id="icon-asterisco-obrigatorio" data-tooltip-id="input-tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Campos marcados com asterisco são de preenchimento obrigatório"></i></label>
                                    <select className="form-select mb-2 " onChange={salvarGrupo} value={selectedGrupo} name="grupo" id="pro-incluir-select" required>
                                        <option value="000000">Grupo</option>
                                        {
                                            jsonGrupos.map(g => {
                                                return <option key={g.gpr_id} value={g.gpr_id}>{g.gpr_descricao}</option>
                                            })
                                        }    
                                        
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                            <Tooltip className="custom-tooltip" id="input-tooltip" place={'right'} style={{ backgroundColor: "#dc3545", color: "white" }}/> {/*basta chamar o componente uma vez que ele servirá para todos os tooltips com aquele ID*/ }
                            <div className="col-lg-1">
                                <button onClick={(e) => handleNovoGrupo(e)} className="btn btn-outline-primary mt-4" id='pro-incluir-select-plus'><i className="fa fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div className="col-lg-4 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Código <i className="fa-solid fa-asterisk fa-2xs" style={{color: "#e41607"}} id="icon-asterisco-obrigatorio" data-tooltip-id="input-tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Campos marcados com asterisco são de preenchimento obrigatório"></i></label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => setPro_Cod(e.target.value)} value={pro_cod} id="pro-incluir-input" type="text" className="form-control"></input>
                                {showTooltipProCod && <Tooltip className="custom-tooltip" id="input-tooltip" place={'right'} style={{ backgroundColor: "#dc3545", color: "white" }}/>}
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-lg-4 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Código Auxiliar</label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => setPro_Cod_Aux(e.target.value)} value={pro_cod_aux} id="pro-incluir-input" type="text" className="form-control" ></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row" >
                            <div className="col-lg-12 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Descrição<i className="fa-solid fa-asterisk fa-2xs" style={{color: "#e41607"}} id="icon-asterisco-obrigatorio" data-tooltip-id="input-tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Campos marcados com asterisco são de preenchimento obrigatório"></i></label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => { setPro_descricao(e.target.value)}} value={pro_descricao} id="pro-incluir-input" type="text" className="form-control"  maxLength="250"></input>
                                {showTooltipProDescricao && <Tooltip className="custom-tooltip" id="input-tooltip" place={'right'} style={{ backgroundColor: "#dc3545", color: "white" }}/>}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-12 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Discriminação, Receita, Aplicação...</label>
                                <textarea onChange={(e) => setPro_discriminacao(e.target.value)} value={pro_discriminacao} rows="3" name="comment" form="usrform" id='discriminacao-pro-incluir' maxLength="400"></textarea>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-2 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Preço<i className="fa-solid fa-asterisk fa-2xs" style={{color: "#e41607"}} id="icon-asterisco-obrigatorio" data-tooltip-id="input-tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Campos marcados com asterisco são de preenchimento obrigatório"></i></label>
                                <NumericFormat className="form-control mb-2"
                                          value={pro_preco1.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})}
                                          allowLeadingZeros
                                          decimalSeparator="," 
                                          thousandSeparator="." 
                                          decimalScale={2} 
                                          prefix={"R$ "}
                                          onValueChange={(values, sourceInfo) => {
                                          setPro_preco1(values.floatValue);
                                }} />                                
                            </div>
                            {showTooltipProPreco1 && <Tooltip className="custom-tooltip" id="input-tooltip" place={'right'} style={{ backgroundColor: "#dc3545", color: "white" }}/>}
                            <div className="col-lg-2 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Data do Preço</label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => setPro_data_preco(e.target.value)}
                                    id="pro-incluir-input" 
                                    type="date"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    value={pro_data_preco}
                                />  
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-2 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Preço Promocional</label>
                                <NumericFormat className="form-control mb-2"
                                          value={pro_preco_promo.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})}
                                          allowLeadingZeros
                                          decimalSeparator="," 
                                          thousandSeparator="." 
                                          decimalScale={2} 
                                          prefix={"R$ "}
                                          onValueChange={(values, sourceInfo) => {
                                          setPro_preco_promo(values.floatValue);
                                }} />                                
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-2 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Início Promoção</label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => setPro_data_ini_promo(e.target.value)}
                                    id="pro-incluir-input" 
                                    type="date"
                                    className="form-control" 
                                    value={pro_data_ini_promo}
                                />    
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-2 mb-3 mb-lg-2" id="coluna-incluir">
                                <label htmlFor="" id="pro-incluir-label">Fim Promoção</label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => setPro_data_fim_promo(e.target.value)}
                                    id="pro-incluir-input" 
                                    type="date"
                                    className="form-control" 
                                    value={pro_data_fim_promo}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="buttons-next mb-4">
                            <Link to={linkVoltar}><button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" >Cancelar</button></Link>
                            <button onClick={(e) => avancar(e)} type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary" id="button-salvar-etapa">Avançar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

);
}

export default ProIncluir;

I also tryed to make 2 useEffect to show the alert but both didn't work
The first one:

```
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location.pathname);

useEffect(() => {
    alert(`The page is about to change to ${location.pathname}`);
}, [!location.pathname]);
```

The second one:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = ''; 
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    };
}, []);
```

Maybe i just need to fix one of they, but i really don't know why they are not warning the page changes.